# What is the Minimum SDK and which one should I choose

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-development

First off, I know very little about android development, I am just getting started.

What is the Minimum SDK choice that you get when creating a project in android studio? Is there a downside to using an older one? And if I follow a tutorial is it essential that I use the same one so I can follow along?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the Minimum SDK choice that you get when creating a project in android studio?

That is the oldest version of Android that you are willing to support. It is expressed in terms of an API level. You can see common API levels in the [Android dashboards](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), and the documentation will point out in many places where things need such-and-so an API level to work.

> Is there a downside to using an older one?

Less stuff in Android will be supported. In your case, since you are following a tutorial, choosing a lower `minSdkVersion` may cause some more complaints from your IDE, saying that such-and-so is not available on your chosen `minSdkVersion`.

> And if I follow a tutorial is it essential that I use the same one so I can follow along?

IMHO, that depends on your overall programming experience. If you are a veteran developer, and you want to play around with a lower `minSdkVersion`, go ahead, bearing in mind that the tutorial code might not run on that API level. If you are fairly new to programming overall, stick with what the tutorial tells you to do. If your concern is that your test device is not new enough for the tutorial, find a different tutorial, find a different device, or use the emulator instead of a device for testing this tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

```
android:minSdkVersion
```

An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute. You should always declare this attribute.

You can use your own min SDK but be careful about features you use. infact, minSDK with great number have more features.